# Removing div on last set of results

Tags: json, ajax

So I'm wondering what is the best way to to remove a view more link on the last set of results.

So for example. I have 10 comments, 5 are shown and I have to click a view more link to get the remaining 5. I then use this to remove the view more link. when response.viewmorecomments is sent back as an empty object

```
    if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(responses.viewmorecomments))
    {
    $("#view"+streamitem_id).remove();
    }
```

Problem I have with this tho, is that I have to click the link again after clicking it for the renaming 5 records for it to remove the link when What I am actually looking for is it to be removed when the remaining 5 records have been returned.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Add a total no. of comments flag and subtract 5 for each click,if 0 or smaller  then remove the div.

Comment: @Mihai That sounds like a great idea. I will see what I can come up with and post any results as soon as I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the server side you can send the total No. of records and No. of records returned in every response.
In your ajax request just maintain a counter in which you will match with your total No. of records. If the value is greater or equal then you can remove the view more option.
Below is the snippet

```
var cnt=0;

.success{
   cnt += response.no_of_rec;
   if(total_no_rec>=cnt){
      $("#view"+streamitem_id).remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic. With a little tweaking this is working perfect. Thank you @Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

use `empty()` instead of `remove()` because the remove() method removes the selected elements, including all text and child nodes.For next comment 5 comments the selected element will not avaliable.

```
if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(responses.viewmorecomments))
    {
    $("#view"+streamitem_id).empty();
    }
```

Comment: for each next five comments dynamically create new `div` having comments then just `append` on previous comment block.